# notifyItemRemoved(); isn't removing the comment from the list until I exit and re-enter the activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update a comments list and I am doing so by using `notifyItemInserted` and `notifyItemRemoved`. When a user adds a comment, the comment is added to the list flawlessly, but the issue arises when I want to remove the comment. The issue that I am experiencing is that when I delete the comment in the list it doesn't just remove the comment right away, it rearranges the list, and the comment is only removed when I exit the activity and then re-enter.

Could someone tell me how to tweak my code so that the comment is removed right away?

**CommentsActivity**

```
public class CommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CommentAdapter mCommentAdapter;
    private List<Comment> mCommentList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, mCommentList, mPostId);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);

        mAddComment = findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
        mImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        mPost = findViewById(R.id.post_comment);

        getImage();
        readComments();
    }

    private void readComments() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                mCommentList.add(comment);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);

                int position = mCommentList.indexOf(comment);

                mCommentList.remove(comment);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mCommentList.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        reference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the ListAdapter class and just pass the new list every time. Let the adapter's internal diff util implementation worry about notifying itself on which item is added/removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that the `onChildRemoved()` method just gives you the key of the removed item and not the value. So what we do is we store the key of each item along with item itself (so that now they are at the same index). When you remove an item the `onChildRemoved()` gets triggered and it will give you the key of the item that was removed.....So now just looking up the index of the removed key, we can safely remove the item itself from the `commentsList`.

**Have a list that stores the keys of the item**

```
public class CommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CommentAdapter mCommentAdapter;
private List<Comment> mCommentList;
//add this
private List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<String>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
............
```

**Add the key at the same time you add the comment:**

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
mCommentList.add(comment);

//add this
keysList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);
}
```

**Now when you remove:**

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

int index = keysList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());

mCommentList.remove(index);
keysList.remove(index);

mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the comment until I exit and re-enter the activity... Same as before. Shouldn't I be using ```mCommentAdapter.notifyItemRemoved();```?

Comment: Okay just follow the steps I updated the answer again.

Comment: You my friend have saved me twice in one day. Thanks a lot! Can you please explain it though a little, so I can understand the thought process. Code works, I just want to make sure I understand what the reasoning behind this is... If you don't mind. Like the key was necessary because...?

Comment: What i understood is that the `onChildRemoved()` method just gives you the key of the removed item and not the value. So what we did is we stored the key of each item along with item itself (so that now they are at the same index). When you removed an item the `onChildRemoved()` gets triggered and it will give you the key of the item that was removed.....So now just looking up the index of the removed key, we can safely remove the item itself from the `commentsList`.

Comment: That's boss man! Thanks a lot for everything. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Okay GoodLuck, glad to help:)